# Banach algebra of homomorphisms

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces. Is it always true that $\mathrm{Hom}(E,F)$ is Banach algebra ?

Comment: Of course not. It is not even closed under composition. But if $E=F$, this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if $E \ne F$.  There's no multiplication.